# Is it possible for a function to be an equivalence relation?

Tags: functions, equivalence-relations

I am not quite sure about my arguments:

1. $aRa$ for every pair $(a,a)$ in $S\times S$, where $S$ — some abstract set. Therefore, every value of a function must be the same as it's argument — $f(x) = x$, for every $x$ in $S$.
2. $aRb \implies bRa$. This will work if our function is the one described above.
3. $aRb, bRc \implies aRc$. Will work also for $f(x) = x$, in case of $a = b = c$.

Is it correct?

Comment: well yes, this is true, however then $f$ is just the identity and you have constructed the standard "equality" relation: $aRb \Leftrightarrow a=b$

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please, learn to use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) to type your questions in this site.

Comment: @jjagmath, okay

Comment: @Lassadar, hah, now I can see it clearly